# is it possible to pass to a function a generic IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, function, ienumerable

I have this function :

```
private void Pager(IEnumerable<t> tEnum)
{
   ...
}
```

and I'd like to pass different IEnumerable, like `IEnumerable<MyObject1>` or `IEnumerable<MyObject2>`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the whole function generic:

```
private void Pager<T>(IEnumerable<T> tEnum)
{
   // here T can be anything
}

// you can call it like:
Pager(new int[]{10,20});
Pager(new string[]{"meep","x"});
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Just make the method generic:

```
private void Pager<T>(IEnumerable<T> tEnum)
{
   ...
}
```

If you look at the LINQ-to-objects extension methods, that's how they do things as well (without the additional `this` prior to the `IEnumerable<T>` as per extension method syntax.)

Comment: I agree your solution is probably what the OP is after but I was just wondering whether `private void Pager(IEnumerable<object> tEnum)` could work. It could imagine it useful not needing to tell the method what type T is. What do you think?

Comment: @Bazzz In .NET 4 that should be fine, since `IEnumerable<T>` is marked as covariant (it's actually declared as `IEnumerable<out T>`). Without knowing the internals of the method, it's hard to say if the approach would be markedly worse, but I think in general it's better to just make the method generic.

Comment: @Bazzz One other point: While it doesn't look like it would apply in the OP's situation, in general, the generic version could accept and use an `IEnumerable<int>` without having to unbox the elements upon enumeration, whereas `IEnumerable<object>` would in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
private void Pager<t>(IEnumerable<t> tEnum)
```